# How to use flask_login and peewee-orm

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I need to create a user loader () with flask login and peewee-orm but when I try this I end up with an error

```
    @login_manager.user_loader()
        def load_user(user_id):
        user = User.get(User.id == user_id)
        if user:
            return user
        return None
```

TypeError: user_loader() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'

Comment: Correct way is to to `@login_manager.user_loader` not with the parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `@login_manager.user_loader()`

should be like this :

```
@login_manager.user_loader
```

That is how you should hook a callback to a decorator anyway.

Read the `Flask-login` docs [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)